# Run script with WebBrowser control (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to scrape a website, and have had some luck using HtmlAgilityPack. But as some of the site uses javascript, I believe I need to use the WebBrowser control (HtmlAgilityPack wont run scripts).

But I am at a complete loss as to how to run the script.

The script in question is associated with a dropdown control - you select a new colour, and different images appear on the page. the dropdown control html looks like this:

```
<ul class="class1"><label class="class2" for="123456_0">Colour</label><div id="123456_0"><select id="123456_Input_0" onchange="updatePanel(0,'123456', true)"><option value="-1">Please select</option><option value="Colour:Green">Green</option><option value="Colour:Navy">Navy</option><option value="Colour:Orange">Orange</option><option value="Colour:White">White</option></select></div><label class="class2" for="123456_1">Size</label><div id="123456_1">Please select the Colour</div><input id="id1" value="123456" type="hidden" /><input id="id2" value="1" type="hidden" />
```

As best as I can tell, when a new colour is select, it runs the updatePanel script. I'm trying to work out how to invoke that using the WebBrowser control, but so far I can make heads or tales out of it.

As best as I can tell, this function has three parameters, so I try to simulate this like this:

```
    object[] objArray = new object[3];
    objArray[0] = 1;
    objArray[1] = "3101";
    //objArray[1] = "3101_Input_Colour:Green";
    objArray[2] = true;
    var resultVar = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("updatePanel", objArray);
```

So - what am I doing wrong? What is the right way to call the script in this scenario?

Comment: have you considered using webdriver to do screen scraping instead?

Comment: In a previous post about how to use HtmlAgilityPack to do this, I was directed to using WebBrowser, so thats what I'm trying now. Never heard of webdriver until you mentioned it.

Comment: Hmmm. Had a bit of a play around with webdriver, and it seems to do the job. I can use the SelectElement.SelectByValue to change the displayed image, then get the urls of the images using driver.FindElement. Maybe I should go with this.